# quiero hacer un sistema de ventas en java, para una licoreria y guardara muchos datos con el paso del tiempo, que base de datos debo usar?

Tags: java

Es mi primer trabajo, aun soy estudiante, quiero hacer un software de ventas para una licorería, con una base de datos local, el lenguaje que usare es java y no se que base de datos usar, a la larga se guardaran muchos datos y no quiero que se congestione o ya no me permita guardar mas datos si es que tiene un limite de datos por tabla.

Comment: Te sugiero MySQL soporta bastante información.

Comment: ¿Cuanto es muchos datos para ti? Sin demeritar tu análisis, me temo que no tienes conciencia de la magnitud de datos actuales y podría arriesgarme a comentar que prácticamente cualquier gestor de base de datos actual te podría funcionar sin problemas,

Comment: una estimacion aproximada de ventas es de 600 productos por mes,lo que sería 7200 registros anuales aproximadamente en una sola tabla, la de ventas, luego en las otras tablas los datos ya son mucho menores.

Comment: Entonces no es "nada" en comparación con bases de datos grandes, yo que tu no me preocuparía tanto, por ejemplo en MySQL si usaras MyISAM tendrías un limite de filas de 4,294,967,296, lo que con tu proyección tardarías 596,523 años en llenarla, y si usaras InnoDB en su lugar ese limite no existe, solo que sea menor a 64TB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu sistema, lo vas a conectar vía intranet (localmente) yo te recomendaría que utilizaras MySQL, es una base muy confiable y te permite generar multiples opciones para tu aplicación. Los requisitos para tu servidor, que en este caso puede ser tu propia maquina, considerando que tú eres el administrador de la aplicación necesitarías (algo muy accesible):

```
- Procesador Core 2 Duo.
- RAM 4 GB (recomendable 8 GB).
- Windows 7 ó si prefieres puedes utilizar Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (genial).
- DD 250 GB
```

Considerando que tu base sea para casi 15,000 a 20,000 transacciones por mes, te quedaría de sobra y te trabajaría muy bien. Aparte que MySQL es gratuito y tiene mucho soporte, es una de las bases mas estables que hay.

Espero que te ayude a decidir sobre tus requerimientos.

Comment: genial, sabes si hay un limite de filas por tabla en MySQL?

Comment: Para el limite creo que puedes checar esta pregunta en stackoverflow en ingles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716232/maximum-number-of-records-in-a-mysql-database-table

Comment: No un limite que puedas alcanzar fácilmente, por ejemplo se recomienda no tener tablas menores a 1TB, y aunque llegaras a ese tamaño podrías particionar la tabla y sobrepasar ese limite varias veces. Como ya te dijeron , normalmente el limite viene de acuerdo a los recursos del SO y o cuestiones de diseño (si no te alcanzara un `int` o `bigint` podrías usar algún otro tipo de datos como un UUID).

Comment: Buena pregunta, míra la cantidad de registros (filas) determina el tamaño de tu base y esta a su vez el performance. Para serte sincero lo mas que yo he incluido en MySQL son 10 millones y te hablo de una base EXCLUSIVAMENTE para transacciones de banco. Por lo tanto yo considero que el limite lo determinas tú como administrador, sin embargo, con base a tu requerimiento pues consideraría que lo hicieras de manera mensual(una base con las mismas características para tu histórico) y esto te permitirá administrarla sin impedir un mejor rendimiento.

Comment: usando el tipo de dato bigint para la clave primaria de la tabla en la que almacenare mas datos, será suficiente? o que tipo de dato usaste para los 10 millones de registros?

Comment: Depende del tamaño de tu clave, ¿va a ser alfanumérica o totalmente entera?. Si es entera te queda de sobra usar big int, considerando una clave de 25 caracteres puedes utilizar int y solo la determinas en el modelo de tu tabla int(25), para tu pregunta, yo utilize el varchar(50) por que tengo un campo que guarda de manera aleatoria la clave de la transacción que realizaba el cliente, era un formato que ya previamente se establecia.

Comment: que me recomendarias? y por que usaste bigint?

Comment: Con `bigint` puedes tener 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 registros, no creo que se quede corto.

Comment: Excelente la información del bigint

Answer (score 1):

tu pregunta es un poco abierta y la respuesta mas adecuada será lo que cumpla con tus requerimientos del sistema a diseñar, del presupuesto que tengas, esto para elegir un motor de bd comercial o un open source. Para que elijas de una mejor manera re recomiendo  plantearte una serie de  preguntas y en función a eso seleccionar la que se adapte mas a las necesidades.

1. A cuantos clientes quiero dar servicio de forma concurrente.
2. Que tamaño de datos voy a necesitar gestionar.
3. Voy a necesitar implementar trabajos en “batch” que accederán a la
   base de datos
4. Qué exigencia de tiempo de respuesta necesito dar a mis clientes
5. Cómo voy a escalar mi base de datos según vaya aumentando el número
   de clientes y transacciones
6. Como voy a monitorizar mi base de datos para conseguir el menor
   posible tiempo de indisponibilidad.
7. Necesito una base de datos relacional o una no SQL
8. Comportamiento de la base de datos ante caída. Como se comporta con
   problemas.

Tienes alternativas como Oracle, MS SQL Server, o My Sql, Mongo DB, etc.

Comment: sera un open source, relacional, almacenare las ventas, productos y empleados, para generar reportes y control, es el primer trabajo que hare y mi temor es que me limite en el almacenamiento de datos, osea si existe un limite de datos por tabla o si es ilimitado, ya que con el paso del tiempo la información se acumulara

Comment: Entiendo, entonces será un mysql, con respecto al tamaño por tabla te comento el máximo tamaño de las tablas es de 65536 terabytes (256 ^ 7 - 1 bytes). Por lo tanto, el tamaño efectivo máximo para las bases de datos en MySQL usualmente los determinan los límites de tamaño de ficheros del sistema operativo, y no por límites internos de MySQL. Como te lo comentaron, usa InnoDB mantiene las tablas en un espacio que puede ser creado a partir de varios ficheros.

Comment: gracias por el dato!

Comment: Para no tener una base de datos de gran tamaño, como buena practica será ir haciendo procesos de BackUp

Answer (score 0):

En primera el tamaño de tu tabla (por así decirlo), depende más de el sistema operativo que del tipo de BD, pero lo que si puede influir es el motor de almacenamiento, te recomiendo utilizar `InnoDB`.

Comment: sistema operativo windows 8, mi temor es que a la larga llegue un momento en el que ya no me permita almacenar mas datos